# VB.net Html convertor error giving no change?

Tags: vb.net

net language.
and I would like to replace the html first tags and keep the structure of the text,  I have tried this code below from  the website https://beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Convert-HTML-To-Plain-Text.aspx

```vb
Dim html As String = "&lt;div class='WordSection1'&gt;&lt;p class='MsoNormal'&gt;"
Dim final_result As String

Dim sbhtml As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(html)
Dim OldWords() As String = {"&nbsp;", "&amp;", "&quot;", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&reg;", "&copy;", "&bull;", "&trade;"}
Dim NewWords() As String = {" ", "&", """", "<", ">", "Â®", "Â©", "â€¢", "â„¢"}
For i As Integer = 0 To i < OldWords.Length
    sbhtml.Replace(OldWords(i), NewWords(i))
Next i
Console.WriteLine($"result after loop : {sbhtml}")

sbhtml.Replace("<br>", "\n<br>")
sbhtml.Replace("<br ", "\n<br ")
sbhtml.Replace("<p ", "\n<p ")

final_result = Regex.Replace(sbhtml.ToString(), "<[^>]*>", "")

Console.WriteLine(final_result)
```

However the output come back as the same as the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for-statement is wrong. It should be

```vb
For i As Integer = 0 To OldWords.Length - 1
```

Probably some C# syntax leaked over.

Why didn't you append the `sbhtml.Replace("<br>", "\n<br>")` and following lines to the `OldWords` and `NewWords`? They are technically not any different.

By using tuples, you can put the old and new words into the same array and use a For-Each-loop

I suggest the following approach

```vb
Dim html As String =
    "&lt;div class='WordSection1'&gt;aaa<br>bbb&lt;p class='MsoNormal'&gt;"
Dim final_result As String

Dim sbhtml As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(html)
Dim Substitutions() As (old As String, repl As String) = {
    ("&nbsp;", " "), ("&amp;", "&"), ("&quot;", """"), ("&lt;", "<"),
    ("&gt;", ">"), ("&reg;", "Â®"), ("&copy;", "Â©"), ("&bull;", "â€¢"),
    ("&trade;", "â„¢"), ("<br>", "\n<br>"), ("<br ", "\n<br "), ("<p ", "\n<p ")}
For Each subst In Substitutions
    sbhtml.Replace(subst.old, subst.repl)
Next
Console.WriteLine($"result after loop : {sbhtml}")

final_result = Regex.Replace(sbhtml.ToString(), "<[^>]*>", "")

Console.WriteLine(final_result)
```

---

The [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/) does a very good job in HTML manipulation and is very reliable. You would do something like

```vb
Dim plainText As String = HtmlUtilities.ConvertToPlainText(html)
```

See [Install and manage packages in Visual Studio using the NuGet Package Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio) for the easy installation of the HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: I need to check what is the difference between \n and <br> ... ?

Comment: It makes no difference whether you replace, for example, `"&lt;"` with `"<"` or `"<br>"` with `"\n<br>"`. You can do it in one go.

Comment: How ?? then beauce what i used to do as decode  html tags. It didn't keep the the structure of the text and so it becomes a huge one piece of text

Comment: You can append `"<br>"`, `"<br "` and `"<p "` to OldWords and `"\n<br>"`, `"\n<br "` and `"\n<p "` to NewWords and do not need to do additional Replaces after the loop. It has the same effect.